# Why I am getting this error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.intCompanyId,
(List<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.ExpItemList, 
"--Select--", 
new 
{ 
    @class = "form-control", 
    @onchange = "GetEmployeeListForthisComp(this.value)" 
})
```

above code gives following error

> Cannot convert type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List<L7HRM.Models.ExpenseItemMaster>' to
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem>'

Comment: paste a screen shot of the Error or copy paste exact Error

Comment: What's the type of ExpItemList ?

Comment: Usually get this type of error when there are different versions of frameworks/assemblies being used. Double check that all version numbers are consistent throughout your projects.

Comment: How was `ViewBag.ExpItemList` assigned? If it's assigned with non-matching type of `List` it will throwing exception.

Answer (score 1):

Because `ViewBag.ExpItemList` is not of type `List<SelectListItem>`